# Stellar Java SDK: Retrieve Account Data

Tags: stellar-core, operations, stellar-sdk, data

I can see how to add data to an account using ManageDataOperation. But is there a way to retrieve the same data using the Java SDK?

I fund a JS example:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/7n4vvt/whats_the_reserve_in_xlm_needed_for_data_storage/

But it suggests constructing the URL yourself and calling horizon. I just wonder if there is a cleaner solution encapsulated into the existing SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use a CallBuilder to retrieve the account object:

```
const server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org')
const callBuilder = server.accounts.accountId(${myPublicKey})
const account = callBuilder.call()
console.log(account)
```

The data entries values are in base64.